# Access local paths and directories in enterprise architect addin

Tags: enterprise-architect

In my addin I look at the GenPath attribute of an element.
In some projects we are using local paths and directories so that GenPath evaluates to something like
%MyROOT%......

Is there a way in my addin to expand the %MyROOT% part of the path

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [EA - Obtain the \`Local Project Path\` directory in the project's \`Version Control Settings\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467510/ea-obtain-the-local-project-path-directory-in-the-projects-version-control)

Answer (score 0):

Access the `paths.txt` file in the %appdata% folder:

`string appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
 string localPathsFilePath= 
                        System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataFolder, @"Sparx Systems\EA\paths.txt");`